How can I query the temp_file_limit value in Aurora/PostgreSQL?
I'm running reporting queries in Aurora/PostgreSQL and a few of them are running out of space with "no space left on device". I googled that the temp_file_limit parameter in PostgreSQL limits the temp space used by queries but, since this is Aurora, there's no access to the underlying installation or OS.
At this point the queries are quite optimized but, since their nature is about reporting, they are resource intensive. If there's no other solution, I can still try cutting the queries in smaller chunks and then stick the results together, but I would prefer not to go that route.
I wanted to know if it's possible to find out the value of temp_file_limit using a SQL query. This could help me deciding if I need to upgrade to a bigger Aurora instance or not. A bigger instance could potentially come with a larger value for this parameter.

Not an Aurora user myself, but did you see this part of the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Reference.ParameterGroups.html

What's wrong with SHOW temp_file_limit or SELECT current_setting('temp_file_limit')?

@LaurenzAlbe Thank you. That's exactly what I needed. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

The question is a duplicate.

For the record, in case this is useful to anyone. Seems like the temp_file_limit is not changeable in Aurora/PostgreSQL RDS. The tiny db.t4g.medium instance has 8 GB, while larger instances (prod grade) have 32-500 GB temp space.
